# StarCraft2: Can a ghost use EMP while sitting in bunker?

Tags: starcraft-2, starcraft-terran

Can a ghost throw an EMP while sitting inside a bunker?

Comment: trough: A long, narrow container, open on top, for feeding or watering animals.
What word did you really mean?

Comment: trough => throw. Sorry for my bad English

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, you cannot use special abilities of units garrisoned inside a bunker, with the exception of stim packs. It's not even possible to individually- or group- select the units inside, though you can direct their fire by right-clicking.

I've just checked and stim is unique in that it can be activated on all units inside the bunker (as long as there's at least one unit inside capable of stimming).

Comment: You can stim marines, that are in bunker. At least I did that in campaign... Is this campaign-only feature?

Comment: Yes, you can stim marines and marauders in a bunker, in both multiplayer and campaign. You can also command the bunkered units to target-fire using right-click or the attack command.

Comment: @Budda , Wikwocket - You are right and I am wrong. Answer edited accordingly. To make sure I make no further mistakes I just tested the rest of the abilities in-game... and unfortunately ghosts cannot use EMP (or snipe, or nuke) from inside a bunker.

Comment: Do medics (in campaign mode, obviously) also heal the stimm'd marines in the bunkers? I think they might.

Comment: I remember SCVs being able to repair a bunker from inside it, but I think that was a bug that has been fixed.

Comment: @Oak - no problem, it is definitely an exception. I suspect it is actually implemented as an ability of the bunker, not a generic pass-through of some unit abilities.